# Select posts with most comments combined with child and parent posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

I have two MySQLi tables set up. One is called "AIW_comments". It has a column titled "post_id" to let me know what post this comment refers to.

I also have a table called "AIW_posts" holding all of the posts.

Now I needed a `mysqli` select statement to retrieve the posts with the most comments first. I got the code working perfectly as expected using:

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT AIW_posts.*
FROM AIW_comments, AIW_posts
WHERE (AIW_posts.id = AIW_comments.post_id AND childPost_id = 0)
GROUP BY AIW_comments.post_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
       , AIW_comments.post_id DESC

       LIMIT $startIndex,$amount") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

I've added the ability to edit a post. I gave "AIW_posts" two new columns "parentPost_id" and "childPost_id". I created a PHP function that gives me an array of the id of every child and parent post given the id of any post.

How do I select the post with the most comments like I did previously but this time include all of the parent and children post comments as if they were the same post?

Comment: There's bound to be a way to do this with the structure you propose, but have you looked into the Nested Set structure? That makes hierarchical data much easier to work with in SQL. Here's a [couple](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/25/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-sql-server/) of [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4155/Improve-hierarchy-performance-using-nested-sets).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL query that will return the data you're looking for:

```
SELECT P.post_id
FROM AIW_posts P
INNER JOIN AIW_comments C ON C.post_id = P.post_id
INNER JOIN AIW_posts PP ON PP.post_id = P.parentPost_id
INNER JOIN AIW_posts PC ON PC.post_id = P.childPost_id
GROUP BY P.post_id
ORDER BY COUNT(C.post_id) DESC, P.post_id DESC
LIMIT 1 -- Or whatever limit you want
```

I choose to only provide you the SQL query instead of the PHP implementation in order to focus on your problem and simplify readability of my answer.

Just few info about my query:

- Instead of using old school syntax for jointure (...FROM table1,
  table2 WHERE...), i used an `INNER JOIN`clause
- I used two additional
  jointures to get the parent and child posts
- For readability purpose,
  my query only returns the `post_id`. To get all columns you want, you
  simply have to add them in the `SELECT` clause and **don't forget to
  add these columns in the `GROUP BY` clause**!

Hope this will help you.